# Are there any other Linux distros (apart from Ubuntu) which allow you to install 'on' Windows?

Tags: linux, unix

Are there any other Linux distros (apart from Ubuntu) which allow you to install 'on' Windows?

I'm having problems installing Ubuntu on my Thinkpad, it keeps breaking down halfway during the installation. I wanted to try another.

EDIT:

I wanted to try and use fedora KDE but it doesnt appear to have the 'windows' installation version?

Answer (score 5):

There is [Wubi](http://wubi.sourceforge.net/), but you probably already know about that.

> 3 Ways to Install Linux 'on' Windows:
>
> http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/3-ways-to-install-linux-on-windows-or-mac/

Comment: what's with the downvote?

Comment: The downvote wasn't me, but I guess it might be because Wubi is probably what's already been referenced in the question.

Comment: @neurolysis: that's what I was thinking which is why I said `but you probably already know about that` - as a way of confirming.  the article I linked also has two more options...

Comment: I didn't say I agreed with the downvote ;) Just seems like that is the most likely reason.

Answer (score 1):

[TopologiLinux](http://topologi-linux.sourceforge.net/index.php?menu=1) is designed out-of-the-box to run on a Windows install.  Looks like it's not been updated in a while, but you might get some use out of it.

There's also [andLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/) which uses the same technique ([coLinux](http://www.andlinux.org/)) which has the additional advantage of being based on Ubuntu, but again, not updated since 2009

Answer (score 0):

You could download VMWare Player.  You could then install whatever linux distribution you want to in it's own guest environment.

You could also try a dual-boot setup where one hard drive partition has Windows and the other has Linux.

Comment: Just adding VirtualBox as an alternative to VMWare player.

Comment: And if you want to use a Microsoft product, VirtualPC.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called [WubiX](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wubix/) but it appears to be abandonware. It's been in the planning stage for years.

For test driving Linux I would recommend using virtual machines instead. Is is much faster to switch between Windows and Linux with for certain tasks and easy to erase and clean up when you're finished. No reboot required, although it does require a little extra processing power (and optionally a separate drive for performance). Another alternative is LiveCDs.

Answer (score 0):

[Jolicloud](http://www.jolicloud.com/) is kind of what you mean, I'm not entirely sure. It's very good and as I understand it installed beside Windows and pretty differently to Ubuntu.

If I were you I might try the text installer of Ubuntu to find the problem.